# Embedding a Report in Criteria Entry Mode in Yii2

Tags: yii2, reportico

Iam trying to embed a report into a view and I've followed the instructions in
http://www.reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php/quickstart/embedding-reports-prepare

but I get the following error

```
PHP Compile Error – yii\base\ErrorException

main(): Failed opening required 'reportico.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')
```

Could anyone help me with this please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need exactly to embed this into a view ? Reportico has a yii2 module, read how to install and use it http://www.reportico.org/yii2/web/index.php/site/installation